# How can you tell when a core data managed object has a dynamic method for setting a toMany relationship?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I have an iOS application that uses core data. I've created a managed object that has a toMany relationship to another object. The application is written in RubyMotion.

When setting the "toMany" relationship of a "group" NSManagedObject object to the person object , I call:

```
group.addPersonObject( person )
```

but I want to make sure that "addPersonObject" exists before I call it. I tried

```
if group.respondsToSelector( "addPersonObject" )
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I assume it is because it is dynamically created by core data.

What is a good way to tell if it exists before I call it?

From other questions on stackoverflow, it seems that respondsToSelect should work since I'm working with an instance of the class but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if group.respond_to?("addPersonObject:")
```

This should work. The : is required because addPersonObject expects an argument.

Comment: Thanks. I tested that one a toOne relationship with my "Submitter" model.  It returned true but when I tried to call the addSubmitterObject method, it gave me an "unrecognized selector sent" error message. The setValue method lets set the toOne relationship.

Comment: You tried the solution I suggested and it returned true but still broke when you called it? That sounds like a RubyMotion bug.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the code that defines up the relationship for my model to lookup if it was a toMany relationship. 
The code is particular to my data structures but it looks like:

```
   # is this a toMany relationship on this class?
   def toMany?(relationship)

      result = false
      relationship = relationship.to_s # in case it was a symbol
      entities = Kernel.const_get( self.class.name ).entityDescription
      entities.each do |e|
        if e.class == NSRelationshipDescription and e.name == relationship and e.maxCount == -1
          result = true 
        end
      end
      result
    end
```